# How to get the variable of count from PHP using ajax/jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to get the variable for count in test.php using ajax/jquery?

The variable that i want to get is that `$countses`. its responsible to hold a value of count for borrow session.

```
    //session_destroy();
if(isset($_SESSION['sBorrow'])){
    $countses = count($_SESSION['sBorrow']);

    echo $countses; 
}
    // nothing requested, so return all values
    print json_encode($_SESSION);
```

I want to call in this place

```
var sessionvar;
            $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
            $.get('test.php' ,function (data) {
                sessionvar = data;
                //var ses = sessionvar.length
                //alert(ses);

                /*
                var count = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < sessionvar.length; ++i){
                    if(sessionvar[i] == 2)
                        count++;
                    alert(count);
                }*/

                var checkedCbs = $('.sBorrow:checked ');
                if (checkedCbs.length === 2) {
                    alert("You can only select 3 books");
                    this.checked = false;       
                }
            });
```

I want to call the variable for `$countses` so that it can be used for conditional statement. However i only get the session variable. So i comment it for a bit while finding the solution.

Comment: only get the session variable? you don't get `json_encode($_SESSION)`?

Comment: i dont know about json_encode. And i still get the result. except i still having problem to use it. can you tell me where to use that json_encode

Comment: oh wait. didnt i already get it? i took the json_encode($_SESSION) right?

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to do.what is `$_SESSION['sBorrow']`? does it hold a array?you shouldn't use echo before json encode.it makes your json invalid.you may need to add count also to json object and return it

Comment: yes it holds an array

Answer (score 2):

Edit the code in Test.php

```
$ret = [];
if(isset($_SESSION['sBorrow']) && is_array($_SESSION['sBorrow']))
{
    $countses = count($_SESSION['sBorrow']);
    array_push($ret,$countses); 
}

array_push($ret,$_SESSION);

print $ret;   
}
```

**ADD this code in ajax**

```
$.get('test.php' ,function (data)
{
var data = data[0];// this is your $countsess
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`test.php`:

```
$ret = [];
if(isset($_SESSION['sBorrow']) && is_array($_SESSION['sBorrow']))
{
    $countses = count($_SESSION['sBorrow']);
    $ret['countses'] = $countses; 
}

$ret['session'] = $_SESSION;

print json_encode($ret);
```

Then your javascript:

```
var sessionvar;
var countsesvar;
.
.
$.get('test.php' ,function (data) {
    sessionvar = data.session;
    countsesvar = data.countses;
    .
    .
});
```